# Why do I see differences when comparing screenshots from YouTube in a browser and the same video downloaded with youtube-dl in VLC?

Tags: graphics, video, youtube-dl

Thanks to this website I know that when I use `youtube-dl` there is no quality loss at all when I download videos.

I picked up one video and I downloaded it in several formats/quality etc.
I made n screenshot using Shutter in full screen of the video that is in the browser, and of the videos that I have downloaded (on VLC, screenshot made with Shutter), on same frame. I put all png picture files in one folder and switch between then back and forth. I see a slight difference.

Did I overlook something?
Different colours (color space)?

Comment: Different decoders may treat video slightly different, and some may even apply filters to the videostream.

Comment: Do you have an idea how i can compare them the right way, so that i  basically, if youtube-dl works as i thought, see no differents when I compare them?